# How to use CSS hover inside html-tag?

Tags: html, css

I want to do something like this:

```
<li style="hover:background-color:#006db9;">
```

But it wont work. Is this possible to do in some way, or do I have to write the css in the head or external css-document?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible using the `style` attribute. You'll have to use CSS, either in the document itself or in an external file.

```
li:hover { background-color:#006db9; }
```

If that's not an option then you'll have to resort to JavaScript.

Comment: Not to mention that those pseudoclasses doesn't work on all browsers. The only reliable resort is JS.

Comment: Agreed. Unfortunately this is the truth :(

Comment: Are there (halfway current) browsers that do not support :hover other than IE < 7?

Comment: Not many. Unfortunately for me IE6 is the only browser "supported" at work, so my perspective is skewed.

Answer (score 33):

It is not possible with inline styles, but the (in)famous onmouseover / onmouseout event handler can do the same thing.

```
<li onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#006db9'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=''">
```

Caveat: CSS definitions with hyphens have to be translated to Javascript using camelCase, like (css)background-color = (javascript)backgroundColor

Comment: you'd the man ;-)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK this can't be done inline without Javascript. You will have to put it into the head or external stylesheets as you already suggest.

A `<style>` tag in the body is also interpreted by all browsers I know but is not valid and therefore not recommendable.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK You can't use pseudo-classes (:hover, :active, etc) on inline css.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just having the `<li>`, you can nest it in an anchors tag `<a href="#" class="hoverable">` and then put this styling at the top of the file or in an external CSS file:

```
a.hoverable:hover{background-color:#006db9}
```

Or you can just use Javascript to avoid using the anchor tag.

I'd recommend [JQuery](http://jquery.com/).