# How do I write a CSS for mouse hover

Tags: php, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use CSS hover inside html-tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834537/how-to-use-css-hover-inside-html-tag)

```
<body>
   <div id="he">
      <div id="header">
         <div class="headertabs">
            <ul class="nav">
               <li class="divide">&nbsp;</li>
               <li class="tab"><a href="a.php">OVERVIEW1</a></li>
               <li class="divide">&nbsp;</li>
               <li class="tab"><a href="a.php">OVERVIEW2</a></li>
</body>
```

How do I write a css when I move the mouse (hover) on the overview1 and overview2 tabs it has to change its text color to green.

Comment: A simple google would of yielded these results :
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/hover.html

Comment: Note that you're missing a lot of closing tabs.

Comment: What do you mean "it has to change its color to green"? Is that the background, the text colour, borders... Question is unclear as to what you want to achieve, as well Googling CSS Hover would of helped massively.

Comment: the text color, overview1 and overview2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simnply use the :hover pseudo selector:

```
li.tab a:hover
{
   color: green
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_/duj2d/

Answer (score 1):

I snagged a bit of CSS from a file I have open that should explain it quite well:

This is my normal CSS for an anchor:

```
a
{
    color: #006699;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This is the bit that changes the color when it is hovered over.

```
a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the hover on the `<a>` instead for better IE support, I'd also change the colour for focus so it changes for keyboard only users when tabbing through links, so:

```
.tab a:hover, .tab a:focus {
  color: green
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
li a:hover{
 color:green;
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

little shorter:

```
    .tab a:hover{color:green}
```